# Test overlap between two gene lists using hypergeometric distribution

Tags: r, overlap

The scope of the hypergeometric distribution is given two gene lists, tests the significance of their overlap in comparison with a genomic background.

The hypergeometric test return p-value. So, if:

- p-value <= 0.05 : we can reject the null hypothesis and assume a significant enrichment, that is, a small probability of seeing an equal or bigger overlap then x.
- p-value > 0.05 : we can't reject the null hypothesis.

I perform 2 analysis.

In the first analysis I have this data:

- group1 = 90 + 506
- group2 = 2636 + 506
- Overlap = 506
- total = 16291

  `phyper(Overlap-1, group1, total-group1, group2, lower.tail=FALSE)`

p-value = 2.92956500029675e-276

So, p-value < 0.05 → I can reject the null hypothesis and assume a significant enrichment, that is, a small probability of seeing an equal or bigger overlap then 506.

In the second analysis I have this data:

- group1 = 238 + 358
- group2 = 220 + 358
- Overlap = 358
- total = 16291

  `phyper(Overlap-1, group1, total-group1, group2, lower.tail=FALSE)`

p-value = 0

So, p-value > 0.05 → I can't reject the null hypothesis.

In the second analysis I'm not able to understand the conclusion. I mean there is 0% of probability to seeing an overlap equal to 358, make it sense? Please, help me to explain the conclusion, because I understood that the significance is high but I'm not able to explain that theoretically.

Answer (score 0):

0 is less than 0.05, You should reject H0 also in your second case.